# push object in objects

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push into my object, here is my code :

```
 credentialsDom = { //my object
  'en': {'template':'html/en_credentials_email.html',
    'mailSubject':'Your solution test credentials​'},
  'fr':{'template':'html/fr_credentials_email.html',
    'mailSubject':'Vos accès à la plateforme de test'}
}

credentialsDom['fr'].push({"data": "data"})
```

and I get :

> credentialsDom.fr.push is not a function

How to push into object?

Comment: The `fr` property is an object, not an array. You can only push to an array.

Comment: `credentialsDom['fr']` is an object

Comment: In case you want to add a property, you can do like this `credentialsDom.fr.data = "data"`

Answer (score 0):

This should work
`credentialsDom.fr["data"]="data"`

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by Nikhil Aggarwal and CertainPerformance, you are mistaking your Javascript object as an array. JS objects do not have a method called "push". Hence the error message when you try to execute that non-existing method to your object. You can add new properties or update existing properties of your JS object by using the dot notation or square brackets.

```
credentialsDom.fr.data = 'data';
```

or

```
credentialsDom['fr']['data'] = 'data';
```

should both work.

You can find out more here : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

PS:
I suggest removing the jQuery tag from this question because the object notation discusssed here is related to pure JavaScript and not jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

[`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) can ONLY be used on `array`'s

So to make it work, you have to assign the new property, instead of pushing a value.

```
credentialsDom.fr.data = "data"; // credentialsDom['fr']['data'] <-- works too
```

```js
credentialsDom = { //my object
  'en': {'template':'html/en_credentials_email.html',
    'mailSubject':'Your solution test credentials​'},
  'fr':{'template':'html/fr_credentials_email.html',
    'mailSubject':'Vos accès à la plateforme de test'}
}

credentialsDom.fr.data = "data";

console.log(credentialsDom);
```